# How to Assign a Query Result to an Integer Array

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
public List<Workflow> GetMyWorkflows(int[] MyRoles)
        {
            int[] myWorkflowIDs = new int[] { };
            RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext();
                var query = from w in context.WorkflowRoles
                            where MyRoles.Contains((int)w.RoleID)
                            select w.WorkflowID;
                var distinctWorkflows = query.Distinct();
                myWorkflowIDs = distinctWorkflows.toArray();
                return myWorkflowIDs;
        }
```

In this method I want to retrieve an array of workflows that a user can 
access.
I get the following error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?[]' to 'int[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve an array of workflows

But your method must return a `List<Workflow>` or a `List<int>`.

So you should skip the array idea. The other issue is between `int` and `int?`. You can solve that in the select clause with `select w.WorkflowID.Value` or `select w.WorkflowID ?? 0`. Or simply `select w` for a `List<Workflow>`.

Also it is a good idea to dispose a context when it becomes unreachable.

```
    public List<int> GetMyWorkflows(int[] MyRoles)
    {
        using (RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext())
        {
           var query = from w in context.WorkflowRoles
                    where MyRoles.Contains((int)w.RoleID)
                    select w.WorkflowID ?? 0;
                    // select w;  to return a List<WorkFlow>

           var distinctWorkflows = query.Distinct();

           return distinctWorkflows.ToList();   // ToList because we are closing the Context
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that WorkflowID is of type `int?`. If you are certain that it cannot be null, change your central query to:

```
var query = from w in context.WorkflowRoles
                        where MyRoles.Contains((int)w.RoleID)
                        select w.WorkflowID.Value;
```

This will ensure that `query` is now of type `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `IEnumerable<int?>`, with the `int` following on throuhh the `Distinct()` and `ToArray()` functions.

Comment: var query2 = from w in context.Workflows
                        where myWorkflowIDs.Contains((int)w.ID)
                        select w;
            List<Workflow> x = query2.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I type that query to get Workflows form Workflow class but it gives me an error: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'RapidWorkflowRepository.Workflow' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RapidWorkflowRepository.Workflow>

Comment: @AnasSalem You're getting `FirstOrDefault()` - which only returns a single object -  and assigning it to a list. Do you want the first one, or all of them (in which case, use `query2.ToList()`)?

Answer (score 0):

So `int?` can also be written `Nullable<int>` which is basically an int that can take `null` values. For example:

```
int? nullableNumber = 5;   // Set to a value
nullableNumber = null?     // Set to null (which is possible because int? is nullable).
```

As you can imagine, `Nullable<int>` is useful for databases because sometimes you might have a column that has null values, and so this type gives a useful means of mapping to this sort of value. The problem, though is that in your code you have to deal with two different types, `int` vs. `int?`. You can cast between the two values by using:

```
// If the nullable-integer is not-null then use it's value, else default to `0`.
int nonNullable = nullableNumber ?? 0;
```

which will replace nulls with `0` if the value is null. Or you can just store your `myWorkflowIDs` in a nullable value (`Nullable<int>[]` or `int?[]`), which semantically better reflects what the column value in the database actually is.

Comment: That will throw an exception if there is a `null` value, not just use a `0`.

Comment: You can use either `GetValueOrDefault` or the null coalesce operator to do that much more concisely.

Comment: Man. I should be giving you rep, heh. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty good error to me

```
Cannot convert type 'int?[]' to 'int[]'
```

You must have an array of type `int?` and be trying to implicitly convert it to `int`.

Therefore you have two options - stop trying to implicitly convert, and allow the result to be `int?[]`, like this:

```
int?[] myWorkflowIDs = new int?[] { };
```

or force the convert to take place, like this:

```
RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext();
var query = from w in context.WorkflowRoles
        where MyRoles.Contains((int)w.RoleID)
        select (int)w.WorkflowID;
        // or w.WorkflowID ?? 0; as necessary
```